# Add minutes to current time in Jenkins pipeline (declarative syntax)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins pipeline code.
Declarative syntax.

I need to get formatted date string for current datetime + 5 minutes.
I can get formatted current datetime with this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
def dateFormat
def date
def formattedDate
...
script {
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    date = new Date()
    formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date)
}
echo formattedDate
...
```

How can i add 5 minutes to date? I've tried use TimeCategory or Calendar, but unsuccessfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see if below code works as expected.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar
def dateFormat
def date
def dateAfterFiveMin
def timeunits
def formattedDate
script {
    date = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeunits= date.getTimeInMillis();
    dateAfterFiveMin=new Date(timeunits + (5 * 60000));
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    formattedDate = dateFormat.format(dateAfterFiveMin)
}
echo formattedDate
```

Comment: Thanks, it works.
Only needed to allow use of script at JENKINS_URL/scriptApproval